# how to set the width and height of the dialog accurately in the mfc2010

Tags: mfc, dialog, size

I can just drag the dialog border, where can I set the specific number.
I can just drag the dialog border, where can I set the specific number.
I can just drag the dialog border, where can I set the specific number.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the IDE you are using, you can manually edit the .rc file, and specify width and height for your [DIALOGEX resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381002.aspx). The values are device independent DLUs. See [Dialog Box Measurements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994.aspx#measurements) if you don't know, what they are.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't know how to open the resource file with the editable ascii format in the vs2010.

Comment: @juncheng: *File* -> *Open*, confirming the prompt to close the file in the resource view, if it is open there. Or rightclick -> *View Code*. Alternatively use Notepad.

Comment: I have find the way to open it, thank you for your answer!